# Recommended Content Popup When User Scrolls Past Certain Point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

On a webpage, when the user scrolls past a certain point (most of the way to the bottom), I would like for a recommended content popup to slide out from the right on the bottom of the webpage.

An example would be on [USAToday](http://www.usatoday.com/story/sports/golf/2014/07/20/rory-mcilroy-british-open-final-day-royal-liverpool-rickie-fowler/12908779/) when you scroll down far enough and the blue recommended box appears, or in the AddThis what's next tool.

How can I do this in the easiest manner including having the "x" button close out the box?

**Edit** For the popup itself. Should I just position a div absolute outside the window and bring it into view or is there another method?

Comment: Use document height and scrollposy then just popup relative positioned div..

Answer (score 1):

Try this for detecting the scroll position. It will run code when the user has scrolled 400 pixels down the page.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 400) {
        // Your code for animating popup box
        alert('Popup box');
    }
});
```

Comment: I think for what he's doing he might want something like the following for the conditional:

    `($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).innerHeight())/$("body").outerHeight() > .8`

Not sure, though.